# Popup to follow progress bar - android

Tags: android

I am trying to do something similar to this popup that show notes and follow the progress bar:

[image: image showcase]

So that the cursor below the popup should follow the progress bar and change the text along the way

where should I start from for creating such popup or is there any ready android widget for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I havent seen any library for this.

You could break it down to the three views. 
- The blue box (top)
- The blue triangle/indicator
- The SeekBar

The triangle/indicator would then `ViewCompat.setTranslationX(indicatorView, seekBarProgress)` inside the onchangelistener on the SeekBar.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: The view downside is progressbar just to show the progress, user cant slide it left or right

Comment: Ahh.. It should still be possible to update the ViewCompat.setTranslationX(indicatorView, seekBarProgress) from the same place you update the progressbar.

Comment: but you know the progress view value is lets say from 0-100, the progress bar will move between those, if I translate the view on X between 0-100 it will stick to the beginning of the screen between 0-100 pixels. wont it?

Comment: @MBH you can draw the view based on the progress on the canvas instead

Comment: I would calculate the x-translation value: `X = (view.getWidth - margin - padding) / 100 * progress;`